# Using OOP and S3 methods to detect, then operate on a single vector OR all columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, r-s3

I wrote a function that operates on a single vector. Sometimes I want to use that function on whole `data.frame`. I can accomplish that by using `sapply` across the relevant variables, but now I want contain and direct the function using S3 methods.

First, the setup:

```
df_test <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                      y = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
                      z = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15))

adder <- function(x, from, to) {
  if(is.null(ncol(x))) {
    x <- structure(list(x = x, from = from, to = to), class = "single")
  } else {
    x <- structure(list(x = x, from = from, to = to), class = "multiple")
  }
  UseMethod("adder", x)
}

adder.single <- function(x, from, to) {
  x <- x + (from - to) # just some random operation here - the real function does more
  x
}

adder.multiple <- function(x, from, to) {
  x <- sapply(x, function(y) { 
    y <- structure(list(x = y, from = from, to = to), class = "single"); 
    UseMethod("adder", y) })
  x
}
```

So on a single vector, the function works:

```
> adder(df_test[,1], 2, 4)
[1] -1  0  1  2  3
```

But passing the entire `data.frame` does not:

```
> adder(df_test, 2, 4)
Error in from - to : 'from' is missing
```

It's clear to me what the problem is - `adder` detects that we're looking at a whole `data.frame`, uses the "multiple" method, which then calls the "single" method and arguments `from` and `to` are not being passed along.

I read Hadley Wickham's [OOP Field Guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) and [Advanced Programming](http://www.pitt.edu/~njc23/Lecture4.pdf) by Nicolas Christian, but it ain't clickin' for me. I welcome a completely different approach, as long as it uses S3 methods because part of this exercise is for me to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `adder` and S3 dispatch will do the right and call the right function.

```
adder.multiple <- function(x, from, to) {
  sapply(x,  adder,from,to)
}
```

You should not define the generic `adder` twice ( the call to `UseMethod`).

Comment: Nice.  Also, I'm guessing OP intended to use `NextMethod` rather than `UseMethod`, though in this case it doesn't make sense due to the weird structure (`multiple` doesn't actually inherit from `single`) even though at first blush it almost seems like it does.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be easier. @BrodieG - I didn't intend to use `NextMethod`, but is that a better way? Also, how should `multiple` inherit from `single`? I'm just learning how to use R in this way now, so I'm open to learning the proper ways to organize my program.

Comment: @christianlemp, in order for `multiple` to inherit from `single`, it must have class `c("multiple", "single")` (i.e. it actually is both classes); this isn't possible in your set-up.  `NextMethod` only really works in situations when you have an object with multiple classes.